# Prevent usb pen drive power down while suspend

Tags: linux, live-usb, power-management

I have problems with resuming normal operation after suspending when booted from live USB pen drive (XUbuntu 16.10).

I figure it's because the USB is powered down and the drive can't be connected back at resume, because I see loads of Ext4-fs "reading directory lblock 0" errors coming up in the terminal.

If this hypothesis is correct, preventing the USB flash drive from powering down could be a solution. Is there a way, given I know my USB flash drive's ID, keep it powered while at suspend?

Answer (score 1):

One of most common problems may happen is kernel shutdown the USB module so power of device would be disconnected . You can check following directory :

```
$ ll  /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1/power/
```

As example there is some file can manage power of USB . This not exact answer for your question but it may help you . Also your can use `modeprobe -a` for searching and reassign devices to device derives .

Comment: Since my flash drive is on Bus 002, I tried to experiment with different values for /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb2/power/autosuspend but no luck. It's very cumbersome to test this, as every change requires full reboot.

Answer (score 0):

That seems like a BIOS config problem, and because of that, this problem could have many solutions.

What you need to do first is to watch if your BIOS configuration could be set to keep alive your USB even when suspended.

Comment: Unfortunately the BIOS settings on USB do not cover anything related to power.